# Setting up email server SPF without access to IP PTR

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, ip, ptr-record

What is or is there a proper way to set up SPF without setting the IP's PTR?
because I don't have access and want to know if there's an alternative method

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I don't know...but I also don't understand why you care about the PTR in relation to your SPF record. What are you trying to do?

Comment: the receiving email server checks the PTR/Reverse DNS of the IP and see if it matches what's in the SPF, at least that's my understanding

Comment: The receiving server likely does, but not for SPF reasons.

Comment: The PTR is not compared against the SPF record. They are completely separate checks.

Comment: so is there a workaround when PTR access is not available?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to meddle with PTR records for SPF.

SPF records on the domain simply need to state what hosts are authorized to send mail from under that domain.

Answer (score 0):

SPF records and PTR records are unrelated.

You should have access to update PTR records. They are handled by your ISP, and all you have to do is request that they add a PTR record for the IP you are paying for.

If you don’t have a PTR record setup, then you are not following best practices, and you shouldn’t be running a mail server like that. It’s likely the mail will be rejected or sent to junk.